# When making unit tests for objective C, how do you test blocks?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, lambda, objective-c-blocks

I have a function (internally uses ASIHTTPRequest) which calls a block with the result:

```
[Http get:@"http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON"
   params:params cacheMins:0 complete:^(NSDictionary *response, BOOL success) {
       STAssertTrue(success, @"JSON retrieved OK");
       STFail(@"blah");
}];
```

I want to test the above, but it seems the test doesn't get called.

How can i ensure that the test waits till the block is called?

-edit-

Of course i don't recommend to do this in the main app in the gui thread, in this particular situation it is only for a unit test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a solution:

[Wait for code to finish execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615939/wait-for-code-to-finish-execution)

Eg:

```
__block int done=0;
[Http get:@"http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON"
   params:params cacheMins:0 complete:^(NSDictionary *response, BOOL success) {
       STAssertTrue(success, @"JSON retrieved OK");
       NSArray *postalcodes = [response objectForKey:@"postalcodes"];
       NSDictionary *first = [postalcodes objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString *adminName1 = [first objectForKey:@"adminName1"];
       STAssertTrue([adminName1 isEqualToString:@"New South Wales"], @"NSW");
       done=1;
}];

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615939/wait-for-code-to-finish-execution
while (!done) {
    // This executes another run loop.
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    // Sleep 1/100th sec
    usleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: Will that sleep(10) not stop the current thread (not the thread running the block)? If its your main thread you launch the block from then the sleep would block the GUI.

Comment: Oops i'll edit that. Should be a 'usleep'. And you're right it'll stop the main thread and stop the gui. However - this is simply for a unit test.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure where I found this, but there's a better way that doesn't use sleeps:

```
while (CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, true) && !placeMarkUpdated){};
```

here it is in context, testing a reverse geocoding request:

```
__block BOOL placeMarkUpdated = NO;

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if (placeMarkUpdated == NO) {
        placeMarkUpdated = YES;
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        address = [Address addressFromPlacemark:placemark];
    }
}];

while (CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, true) && !placeMarkUpdated){};
```

Sleeps suck cause they slow down the build (I know 5s doesn't sound bad, but consider the old story: guy goes to doctor cause his knees hurt from running, Doctor says 'get up on the table' and taps his knee and says 'does that hurt?' guy says 'no,' doctor: 'it would if I did it 10K times...'