# Is it worth to run the HTTP request in a new thread?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, http

I made an app in Objective c that receives and sends data from the server through an HTTP request. It works fine but when I connect to the school's Internet the app freezes. I figured that the wifi is too slow and I thought of making a new thread and throw in an HTTP request and keep the thread alive until the app is done with connectivity, so it does not conflict with the main interface.

The problem is that I'm not quite familiar with threads and I want to know if it is worth doing it this way.

Comment: Not only worth it ... I'd say pretty much required.  [Check out this] (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:) which does the GCD work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provides a asynchronous, non-blocking API for handling HTTP requests. We wanted to be able to wait for the HTTP request to return with the result. Specifically, we are posing an event to Facebook and we want to know the FacebookEventID of the event that we just posted.

In order to do that, we created a variable “postRequestReturned” and set it to false. In the post function, we send the request and then block the thread as long as “postRequestRetured” is false. A point to note here is that a simple while loop resulted in blocking the Main thread and making the application unable to receive the response from Facebook. Instead, we used the Runloop libraries in objective c,
Runloop is a loop your thread enters and uses to run event handlers in response to incoming events. Some good documentations

[Wait for code to finish execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615939/wait-for-code-to-finish-execution)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html

The code snippet that we used

```
while(!postRequestReturned){

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];

}
```

In the completion handler for the Facebook request, we set the postRequestReturned variable to true.

Courtesy:
[Wait for HTTP request to finish in obejective-c for iOS](https://yunmingzhang.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/wait-for-http-request-to-finish-in-objective-c-for-ios/)

Answer (score 0):

Execute the web request call using the Asynchronous API's

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:]
```

or

```
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:m_webRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES]
```

An async call is not going to block your main thread.